# External monitor turns off randomly (+ during software update prompts)

Tags: display

I have a MacBook Pro 2014 connected to [an external LG monitor](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-29wp50s-w-ultrawide-monitor) via (stock) HDMI.

The monitor turns off randomly every now and then: the only pattern that I could notice is, it turns off every time a software update is prompted.
Granted, it turns on again a few seconds after I moved and clicked the mouse, but this continuous interruption is extremely annoying.

I suspected driver problem, but it doesn't seem like a Mac version of the driver is available.

Does anyone has any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you mean it turns off when an OS System update is offered, or an App Store update? The former should be very infrequent (assuming you are updating). But App Store updates might be checked "on the hour", and it could just be a coincidence that something else is triggered at that point. I'd check the cable first of all, though. Then see if the display is set to go to sleep after a set time -- is there a control panel menu on the display itself?

Comment: Hi @benwiggy, thanks for your reply. I mean the former, doesn't seem like a coincidence (observed it every single time) - also, it is not the only pattern, except that I couldn't find any other patterns yet. I have changed the HDMI cable and seems like the issue still persists. As for the display setting, it is set to rest after 3 hours of inactivity (the longest possible among the finite time options). Nevertheless, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Sonoma 14.1 was released on Wednesday. Did the monitor turn itself off when you were prompted to update?